# Selenium webdriver failing to launch chromedriver with no error output

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use Selenium Webdriver (chromedriver) in python to automate a webscraping process.
My program did work at one point, but it had been a while since I ran it.
I Narrowed down the issue to the launching of chromedriver, so i took that part of the code (which happens to be the top of the code) out on its own to see if it was something after ti causing the issue, but it presents the same problem.

The Code is:

```
try:
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
    import time
    import pandas as pd
    #import lxml
    import html5lib
    #import xlwings as xw
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import itertools
    import openpyxl
    n = int(0)
    errornumber = int(0)
    rw = int(1)
    lcfname = (0)
    df4 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['1','2','3','4','5'])
    df3 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\jjdef\OneDrive\Desktop\give\names.csv", sep=',')
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.headless = True
    options.add_argument("--log-level=0")
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    options.binary_location = "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
    df0 = pd.DataFrame()
    starttime = time.ctime()
    num = len(df3)
except:
    print('errorininitials')

try:
    print('0')
    web = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=Service(r'C:\Users\jjdef\OneDrive\Desktop\give\chromedriver.exe'))        
    print('s1pass')
except:
    print('s1fail')
```

And I get an output of:

```
PS C:\Users\jjdef\OneDrive\Desktop\give\copyright> python new3.py
This program was written and is owned by John (JJ) DeFeo, Copyright Pending. See line 1 for more info. By using this program, you aknowledge and agree to the terms in line 1 of the code.
0

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:57777/devtools/browser/2e99eeeb-1ee8-4449-8ca0-0df0d6f38569
s1fail
```

I have no clue what is causing this issue. I updated chromedriver, chrome is up to date, I turned on the headless setting, etc.

Thank you in advance to anyone with any idea whats going on.

Comment: Have you tried removing try/except statements to see the actual error?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, I downloaded the most recent stable update of chromedriver, not the one that was the closest match to the version of Chrome I was on.